# Cannot query the value of property 'namespace' because configuration of project ':app' has not completed yet

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am upgrading gradle from 6.2 to 7.3.3 but I am getting the error on

```
Cannot query the value of property 'namespace' because configuration of project ':app' has not completed yet.
```

This error comes when I comment the below code

```
//    javaCompileOptions {
//      annotationProcessorOptions {
//        includeCompileClasspath true
//      }
//    }
```

If I uncomment the code I get below error

```
No signature of method: build_e2h4qa61bft5s0ue8tk1wwyzn.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_e2h4qa61bft5s0ue8tk1wwyzn$_run_closure5) values: [build_e2h4qa61bft5s0ue8tk1wwyzn$_run_closure5@2c96e5dc]
```

this method might be removed from gradle 7.3.3 but I could not find the solution for the first error. I tried with --stacktrace, --debug --info but not getting enough info to solve this.

Comment: you can try commenting only `includeCompileClasspath true` or `annotationProcessorOptions {
//        includeCompileClasspath true
//      }`

Comment: so how you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue, the bellow method helped me, you can try it too.

1-> Go to your build.gradle(AppName) file

2->edit the kotlin version to the latest plugin version that you have installed in your Android studio.

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'                <--------------------------------

}

Answer (score 0):

update your kotlin version

---->ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This error was caused for an outdated version of the Kotlin version plugin:

> Cannot query the value of property 'namespace' because configuration
> of project ':app' has not completed yet

We need to use a new version according to the Android Studio and Gradle version used in your project.

[image: Jorgesys kotlin-gradle-plugin]